# Prophet not fitting data correctly

Tags: time-series, python, change-point, prophet

I'm currently looking to build a time-series model to do change point detection on a churn dataset, in order to check that the covid19 measures taken during the pandemic had an influence on churn.

I'm currently using Prophet to create the model, but i don't seem to be able to predict correctly the change points during the pandemic, nor are the data points fitted correctly:

[image: Time series data]
[image: Prophet fit]
[image: Change points]

As you can see in the second image, the data is clearly not fitted well, and cant capture the churn variation over time. Furthermore, there are a lot of changepoints in locations with not much change, and no points in some of the events. Below is what i've tried:

```
model.fit(data)
future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=100)
forecast = model.predict(future)
```

Can you guys help me out figuring out what i'm doing wrong? Or if Prophet is the right tool for this task (detecting changepoints, and hopefully matching them with the ones from real covid events)?

thank you in advance!

Comment: If I had to guess from the pictures, you are probably plotting just the trend and throwing away the seasonality part of the series.